# Confused about this array pulled from a Google Docs Spreadsheet using PHP and fopen()

Tags: php, arrays, google-docs

Here is the code which I am using to pull data from a public google docs spreadsheet (exported as a CSV).

```
<?php
// link to Google Docs spreadsheet
$url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=xxxx&output=csv';

// open file for reading
if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $totalrows = count($data);
        for ($row=0; $row<=$totalrows; $row++)
        {           
            if (strlen($data[$row])>0)
            {

                $firstname = $data[1];
                $surname = $data[1];

                echo $firstname;
                echo $surname;
            }
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
exit;

?>
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
MartinMartin

Array
(
    [0] => Firstname
    [1] => Martin
)

CarlinCarlin

Array
(
    [0] => Surname
    [1] => Carlin
)
```

I am just confused as to what I am doing wrong, I am looking to be able to set the data as variables so that they can be echoed later in the script.

i.e.

```
<?php echo $firstname; ?>
```

Should echo `Martin`, not `MartinMartin`.

This is how the data is stored in the spreadsheet:

```
    A          B
1  Firstname Martin
2  Surname   Carlin
```

Any help appreciated!

**Update**

Changed the structure now as follows (sorry for the long-windedness and repetition):

```
// open file for reading
if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        for ($row = 0; $row < count($data); $row += 2)
        {
            $firstname = $data[$row][1];
            $surname = $data[$row + 1][1];
        }



    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo 'Firstname: '.$firstname.'<br /><br />';
echo 'Surname: '.$surname;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting MartinMartin because you are setting firstname and surname to the same data[1] value and echoing both out together per row iteration. If you comment out echo $surname, you will find that it does just output Martin. Bear in mind that Martin's surname Carlin is on a different row to his first name too, so you won't be able to just do $surname = $data[1] to get it. You would need to look ahead to the next row to get his surname. You'd probably want to iterate the $row array in 2-step fashion so you could index $data[$i][1] and $data[$i + 1][1] for first name and surname.

```
$rows = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $rows[] = $data;
}

fclose($handle);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($rows); $i += 2) 
{
    $first = $rows[$i][1];
    $surname = $rows[$i + 1][1];
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will update my question with a slightly new structure. Just wondering how to extract the individual pieces of data from the arrays now?

Comment: What is the output of your script now that you updated it to use $row and $row + 1? You also need to add the [1] index to each line, e.g. $firstname = $data[$row][1]; and $surname = $data[$row + 1][1];

Comment: output is : `Firstname: a

Surname: ` if left as in the update in the question it is just the same bug : `Firstname: Carlin

Surname: `

Comment: This is not that hard, just debug your $data[$row] with print_r or something to understand the row structure, and read up on indexing multidimensional arrays. See my code update above. It's kind of difficult understanding what you are doing with what you've described so far.

Comment: thanks but that still doesn't work, it's the same output as my previous comment. What I am trying to do is set each value as a variable so I don't want to `break` or anything like that, say I had Firstname, Surname, Address, E-mail Address labels in column A and their corresponding values in the same row in column B, I want to set a variable to each value. Hopefully that makes some more sense now and that it's actually possible somehow.

Comment: Well, I ran my sample code and it's fine. I get Martin Carlin. See https://gist.github.com/2713720

Comment: yeah it will probably be perfect for the array you made but if you see what I get when I do a `print_r` in my question you'll see that each key/value pair ends up in it's own individual array, not in the same one.

Comment: No my code is setup the same as yours. But I think I see the issue. $data is your row. The loop inside your while for ($row=0; $row<=$totalrows; $row++) is actually iterating over your columns in the $data row. Remove it. You will need to track $row as an int outside the while and on every iteration increment it by 2 ($i += 2). Then just have your var assignments in the while using $data[$row][1] and $data[$row + 1][1]

Comment: my apologies, I read your code wrong, I didn't see that each line was a separate array. I think the only difference is I don't have an array with the column names, i.e. A and B. I updated my question with the code I am now using but the output is just `Firstname: u

Surname: a` and I have no idea why.

Comment: As I said, your inner for loop is iterating the columns of the data row forcing your indexing to grab single letters. See my updated code - untested, but in the right direction. Sorry, updated the code again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11347/discussion-between-porridgebear-and-martincarlin87)

Answer (score 1):

The way the document is laid out, each time the while statement loops you get either the firstname or surname.  Not both within the same loop.  You should either refactor the spreadsheet to be:

```
    A - Firstname      B - Surname
1   Martin             Carlin
2   Next               Name
```

or you'll need to add the firstname and then the surname on alternating loop revolutions

Comment: thanks. I would change the spreadsheet structure if all I was storing were firstnames and surnames but I am aiming to store lots of attributes once I can figure out how to get each piece of data individually....